# How do you use Ecto.Changeset.check_contstraint/3 to check the same constraint on multiple fields?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I ultimately want to have a check constraint on a few of my fields that if any one of them are not null, then I want none of them to be null.

I have a working check constraint for this, but when I apply it to my `Ecto.Changeset` using [check_constraint/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#check_constraint/3) I can only use it on 1 field at a time.

So I assumed that I would just pipe them together. If the constraint errored on multiple fields, it would add the error to each field.

Like this:

```
%Ecto.Changeset{
    valid?: false,
    errors: [*error_for_field_one*, *error_for_field_two*, *error_for_field_three*]
} = 
    changeset
    |> check_constraint(:field_one, :my_constraint, message: "this doesn't work") 
    |> check_constraint(:field_two, :my_constraint, message: "this doesn't work") 
    |> check_constraint(:field_three, :my_constraint, message: "this doesn't work") 
    |> etc.
```

Unfortunately this does not happen, I only get the last error in the chain of `check_constraint`s that fail.

How do I get the same check constraint on multiple fields to get the changeset errors on each field that the constraint fails on?

Comment: You're using `check_constraint/4`, which does not exist. There is only [check_constraint/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#check_constraint/3), or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are totally right, I have been using the function incorrectly. thanks for pointing it out. I cannot believe I didn't catch that

Comment: `changeset  |> check_constraint(:field_one, name: :my_constraint_one) |> check_constraint(:field_two, name: :my_constraint_two) |> check_constraint(:field_three, name: :my_constraint_three)`
I'm having the same problem
Do you have a solution that will bring all the errors together?